# ASP.NET Core передача файла клиенту размером более 2Гб

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7

```
public IActionResult Download2()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_fileBufferDownloadStorage.GetFolderPath(), "03d4f3bd-b175-4320-a432-38f393da202b");

    var fileStreamDownload = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    return new FileStreamResult(fileStreamDownload, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"))
    {
        FileDownloadName = "1.zip"
    };

    //return new PhysicalFileResult(filePath, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

При выполнении данного кода получаю ошибку `Stream was too long.` Т.к. происходит буферизация в память.

А мне нужно передавать пользователю фалы размером более 4GB.
В какую сторону копать? Или как отключить буферизации?

Comment: Вроде код рабочий, скорее всего, где происходит считывание всего потока, возможно в middleware.
Покажите весь стек ошибки и навести атрибут HttpGet на Download2.

Comment: Сохраняйте файл на диск в публичную папку и отдавайте как статику. Пусть HTTP сервер отдаёт, а не ваш код. 1) это экономит ресурсы 2) вообще не надо писать код передачи, а просто бросить редирект на скачивание. 3) версия дотнета какая?

Comment: Код рабочий. Качает файлы размером меньше int32. При выполнении FileStreamResult используется MemoryStream, как это обойти не знаю

Comment: Используется он не асп.нет же. Взял ваш код, создал свежий проект на .net 7 и спокойно скачался файл 6гб. А значит у вас есть какой-то middleware с MemoryStream

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52547167/12888024 оно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто помог. Особенно помог [vitidev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191496/vitidev), я нашёл middleware с MemoryStream

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]